# Sum the first n numbers (from 1 to n) using loops in C

Tags: c, loops, runtime-error

I want to create an algorithm that allows you to sum the first n numbers (from 1 to n) once the user is asked to enter n from the keyboard.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    int x,k,j;
    
scanf("%d",&x);
    
    int y= 1;
    
do {
    
    int k= y;
    
    int y= y+1;
    
    int j= k+y;
    
}   while(y<x);


printf("The Total sum of the number is: %d ", j);
    

}
```

I have wrote this but it gives me this error:

```
[Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1):

You already initialized y, j and k. There is a simplier way to count sum from 1 to n.

```
scanf("%d", &n);
int sum=0;
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
    sum=sum+i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Variables are not initialized.

2.Re-create variables too many times resulting in no saved values.

3.Hard to read.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int end = 0, sum = 0;
    scanf("%d",&end);
    int i = 1;
    do {
        sum = sum + i;
        i= i+1;
    } while(i<=end);

  printf("The Total sum of the number is: %d ", sum);
}
```